# proper way to delete query in PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I'm getting used to using PDO and running some commands, although this code below works it's not giving any errors even when i deliberately try to make it fail by doing: `` WHERE `url_id`='{11$_GET['shortnerId']}' ``

```
        $db5 = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=admin_xxx", "admin_xxx", "xxx");
        
        if ($_GET['do'] == "delete") {

            try {

                if ($db5->query("DELETE FROM `urls` WHERE `url_id`='{$_GET['shortnerId']}'")) {
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> <strong>URL shortner</strong> has been <strong>deleted</strong>.</div>';
                } else {
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Error!</div>';
                }                   
                
            }
            catch (PDOException $e)
            {
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'><i class='fas fa-exclamation-triangle'></i>{$e->getMessage()}</div>";
            }       
            
        }
```

As strange as it is for working code, is this the proper way for a delete query in PDO? it is working but I would like to do it the proper way if this is not the standard way top do it, any information is appreciated.

Comment: For security reasons, you always want to use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) whenever you are passing uncontrolled (user supplied) data to the database. This is true for all query types including `DELETE`, `SELECT`, etc. Even if you think you are sanitizing the data, it is still safest to pass it this way. In fact, unless you are passing literals, I would recommend always doing it this way just as a best practice to get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a MySQL Delete command, using PHP's PDO Prepared Statement;

```
$stmt = $db5->prepare("DELETE FROM urls WHERE url_id=?");
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['shortnerId']));
```

For further information on how to use PHP PDO Prepared Statements, have a look at their website here;
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php